# Displaying files on the file server from frontend side (angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, image, fileserver

I have an angular application, this application works with a .net core api. The file upload process is uploaded to a file server over the selected files. However, it does not appear when I want to use this file on the front side.

I tried to send a request in the IP of the file server but it still didn't work.

simply

file server path like this

```
//acdc/queen$/my_directory/spesific_file_name.extention
```

When i called this path as below

```
<img src="//acdc/queen$/my_directory/spesific_file_name.extention" class="attahement__img" />
```

or

```
<a class="attahement__link" href="//acdc/queen$/my_directory/spesific_file_name.extention"><i class="far fa-file-word attahementlink"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using .net core on api side. You can serve static files as uploads that will be display with another folder or server

[Serve static files on .net core 3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1)